# How to export returned datatable to excel with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Sounds simple, but I do not know where to start.

My site has a series of selections the user picks from. From that selection, a query is built, and data is pulled from the database.  It is then returned in a table format.

At this point, the data is displayed and the user can click a button to export the records into an Excel sheet.

Here is the query:

```
 <?php 
   function displayrecords(){
   $place = $_GET['place'];
   $time = $_GET['time'];
   $name = $_GET['name'];
   $sql_json = "";
   $where = "";
   if($place != ""){
     $where = " `place` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($place)."'";
   }
   if($time != ""){
     if( $where != "" ) $where .= " AND ";
     $where .= " `time` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($time)."'";
   }
   If($name != ""){
     if( $where != "" ) $where .= " AND ";
     $where .= " `name` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'";
   }

   if ($where != "") $sql_json = "SELECT * FROM `database`" . " WHERE " . $where . ";";
   $QueryResult = @mysql_query($sql_json) or die ('<div>Use filters to search</div>');
   $resnum = mysql_num_rows($QueryResult);
   if ($resnum == 0){
     echo "<div>Your search returned no results</div";
   }
   else {
     echo "<table>\n";
     echo "<tr><th>Place</th>" . "<th>Time</th>" . "<th>Name</th></tr>\n";
     while(($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) !== FALSE){
     echo "<tr><td>{$Row[place]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$Row[time]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$Row[name]}</td></tr>";
   };
   echo "</table>\n";
   }
   }
   ?>
```

I can call the function in html at this point:

```
 <?php displayrecords(); ?>
```

Then here is my button used to export:

```
 <input class="btn btn-success btn-small" type="submit" name="get_report" value="Get Report" />
```

And this is where I'm stuck.  I know I might have to use javascript or something.  Please provide me some insight.  No need to down my code.  I'm using regular mysql, not mysqli or pdo.

Please tell me what I need to do next to make the button work so it exports to an Excel sheet.  I'd appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: [phpexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) or something similar

Comment: Clicking a button and exporting to Excel are 2 very different things.

Comment: if there are no formatting requirements, consider a csv file, for greater support and easier development

Comment: Separate your logic so you have the fetching-from-db and display-to-user separate. That way you can CHOOSE how to output the data. Right now you'd have to add more layers of if() or duplicate entire chunks of the code to produce user output and excel output.

Comment: @Sebastien, you're really splitting hairs there. I think it is pretty obvious what the OP is looking for. Have a look at this http://davidvielmetter.com/tricks/howto-convert-an-html-table-to-csv-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

Just check if button was pressed end return html or excel data accordingly.

```
   if ($resnum == 0){
     echo "<div>Your search returned no results</div";
   }
   else {
     if (isset($_POST['get_report']){
         // Use phpExcel class or just echo CSV formatted text with headers telling the browser its a CSV file
     }else{
       echo "<table>\n";
       echo "<tr><th>Place</th>" . "<th>Time</th>" . "<th>Name</th></tr>\n";
       while(($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) !== FALSE){
         echo "<tr><td>{$Row[place]}</td>";
         echo "<td>{$Row[time]}</td>";
         echo "<td>{$Row[name]}</td></tr>";
       }
   }
```

[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) library to get your data into excel. It's free and very easy to use. In your case you could do the following:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$excelRow = 1; // just an integer to track where in the sheet we are
while(($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) !== FALSE)
{
  // This only puts the data into the spread sheet and does not print it

  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' . $excelRow, $Row['place']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B' . $excelRow, $Row['name']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C' . $excelRow, $Row['time']);

  $excelRow++;
}

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('myfile.xlsx')); // or stream the file contents to output buffer so the user downloads it.
```